# SQL - Count of Values Based on Multiple Keys

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to SQL and trying to create a query to return a count of unique values, but whether a row is counted depends on the value of another row that is related. I am unsure if this can be done by 'Group By' or some other function.

Let me try to explain. Here is what the data looks like. There is an indeterminate number of lines. For simplicity, I'm illustrating only two allowed values for each ITEM_NUMBER.

```
CUSTOMER_ID ITEM_NUMBER LINE    DISPLAY_VALUE
1           10          1       A
1           20          1       Y
1           30          1       C
1           10          2       B
1           20          2       X
1           30          2       C
2           10          1       B
2           20          1       X
2           30          1       D
2           10          2       A
2           20          2       Y
2           30          2       D
```

Now, I only want to return valid lines for a CUSTOMER_ID when the value for ITEM_NUMBER 20 on the corresponding LINE/CUSTOMER_ID is equal to 'X'. These would be the first set of filtered results.

```
CUSTOMER_ID ITEM_NUMBER LINE    DISPLAY_VALUE
1           10          2       B
1           20          2       X
1           30          2       C
2           10          1       B
2           20          1       X
2           30          1       D
```

Next, I want to get a count grouped by DISPLAY_VALUE and ITEM_NUMBER.
Sample Code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Count', DISPLAY_VALUE, ITEM_NUMBER
FROM tmp.DB
GROUP BY DISPLAY VALUE, ITEM_NUMBER
```

Ideally, it would return the following:

```
Count   ITEM_NUMBER    DISPLAY_VALUE
2       10             B
2       20             X
1       30             C
1       30             D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test this but I think you need the following:

```
select count(*),DISPLAY_VALUE,ITEM_NUMBER
from tmp.DB
inner join (
   select LINE,CUSTOMER_ID 
   from tmp.DB
   where DISPLAY_VALUE = 'X'
   ) x on x.LINE=tmp.DB.LINE and x.CUSTOMER_ID=tmp.DB.CUSTOMER_ID
group by DISPLAY_VALUE,ITEM_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks Phil! This worked like a charm. For future reference, is there a SQL term for using a select within an inner join to limit results?

Comment: @Matt - I'm not aware any term for such but the technique is a common design pattern so it probably ought to have one-  There may be an opportuinity there for us to coin a term and get some recognition on wikipedia :)